# Procesar el texto seleccionado de un área de texto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy programando en *JavaScript* y *HTML*, y tengo un `textArea` *(área de texto)*, y un `div` donde muestro el `resultado` de haber procesado el contenido del `textArea`.

Pero lo que quiero es procesar el *texto seleccionado*. Es decir, que el `resultado` sea:

> #### Marcar en negrita y tamaño grande la parte seleccionada.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function procesar_selección(texto)
{
  return texto
}
function procesar_selección_html()
{
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto_html").value
  resultado.innerHTML = procesar_selección(texto)
}
```

```css
textarea{
  height: 100px;
  width : 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>Escriba el texto a procesar:</div>
<textarea
  id = "texto_html"
  onkeyup   = "procesar_selección_html()"
  onkeydown = "procesar_selección_html()" >
</textarea>
<div id="resultado" ></div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para procesar el *texto seleccionado*, es necesario acceder a dos propiedades que tiene la etiqueta `textArea`.

- La propiedad `selectionStart` es un entero que indica la posición del *inicio de la selección*.
- La propiedad `selectionEnd` es otro entero, que indica la posición del *fin de esa selección*.

Primero hacemos una función para obtener el `textarea` *(el área de texto)*. Para esto usaremos `document.getElementById` y obtenemos el elemento que tiene `id` con valor `"texto_html"`:

```
function obtener_textarea(){
    return document.getElementById("texto_html")
}
```

En este caso, se hace una variable llamada `área_texto`y se le asigna lo que devuelve la función `obtener_textarea()`, entonces el `textarea` será la variable `área_texto`. Además hacemos una función similar para el área del resultado, la llamaremos `obtener_área_resultado()`.

Para acceder a las propiedades `selectionStart` y `selectionEnd`, simplemente hay que hacer `área_texto.selectionStart` y `área_texto.selectionEnd`. Una vez declaradas las variables con estas posiciones, hago lo siguiente:

```
obtener_área_resultado().innerHTML=procesar_selección(texto,inicio,fin)
```

Esto significa que estoy asignando el resultado de procesar la selección en el *centro*, junto con el inicio del texto a la *izquierda*, y el final del texto a la *derecha*. Todo eso construido como un solo texto plano, que el motor *HTML* le dará estilo porque lo estoy asignando a un `div`.

La función `procesar_selección`, lo que hace es cortar el texto en tres partes.

- La del `inicio` es desde el inicio de lo escrito en el área de texto hasta el inicio de la selección.
- La del `centro` es desde el inicio de la selección hasta el fin de la selección.
- La del `fin` es desde el fin de la selección hasta el fin de lo escrito en el área de texto.

Por último, se concatena las tres partes, pero se encierra la parte del `centro` con etiquetas `b` y `big`, para que se muestre en *negrita* y *grande*.

Además de llamar a la función al presionar las teclas del teclado mediante `keydown` y `keyup`, hice que llame a la función mediante el movimiento del ratón, usando `mousedown`, `mouseup` y `mousemove`. Todo esto se hace con la propiedad `addEventListener`.

Código completo:

```js
function obtener_textarea(){
  return document.getElementById("texto_html")
}
function obtener_área_resultado(){
  return document.getElementById("resultado")
}
function procesar_selección(texto,inicio_selección,fin_selección)
{
  var fin_texto = texto.length

  var inicio = texto.slice(0               ,inicio_selección)
  var centro = texto.slice(inicio_selección,fin_selección   )
  var fin    = texto.slice(fin_selección   ,fin_texto       )

  centro="<b><big>"+centro+"</big></b>"

  return inicio+centro+fin
}
function procesar_selección_html()
{
  var área_texto = obtener_textarea()

  var texto  = área_texto.value
  var inicio = área_texto.selectionStart
  var fin    = área_texto.selectionEnd

  obtener_área_resultado().innerHTML=procesar_selección(texto,inicio,fin)
}
function agregar_eventos(elemento_html){
  var eventos = ["keyup","keydown","mousedown","mouseup","mousemove"]
  for(var i in eventos){
    elemento_html.addEventListener( eventos[i], procesar_selección_html )
  }
}
agregar_eventos( obtener_textarea() )
```

```css
textarea{
  height:100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<p>Escriba un texto y luego seleccione una parte para procesarlo:</p>
<textarea id="texto_html"></textarea>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: buenas tardes como se pude agregar etiquetas al textarea que cuando se salve el contenido de ese textarea se guarde lo que esta dentro de las etiquetas en un arreglo independiente

Comment: @albertolg89 No entiendo exactamente la pregunta, podrías hacer una nueva pregunta en el sitio. Acá no estoy manejando ni etiquetas, me imagino que HTML... Tampoco arrays (salvo para los eventos), ni sé lo que significa salvar... Solamente proceso el seleccionado del textarea.

Comment: lo que quiero es saber como puedo guardar lo seleccionado en un arreglo con javascript

Comment: @albertolg89 Lo seleccionado es la variable `centro`... Entonces se haría `var array = []; array.push(centro)`

Comment: Quisiera hacer otra pregunta, como puedo a esa selección ponerla entre dos etiquetas ejemplo <acuerdo>esto es una acuerdo</acuerdo> que cuando se guarde para la base de datos se recorra todo el texto y se vaya guardando lo que esta dentro de <acuerdo> y después me permita eliminar esa etiqueta acuerdo. Esta un poco enredada la pregunta. Pero es que quisiera hacer una especie de reconocimiento de texto buscando información especifica y almacenándola en base de datos

Comment: @albertolg89 El string concatenado a las etiquetas quedaría así... `var etiqueta = "acuerdo"; var cadena = "<" + etiqueta + ">" + centro + "</" + etiqueta + ">" `, y luego para volver a separar las partes, se puede usar una expresión regular `var partes = [...cadena.match(/(<[a-z]+>)(.+)(<\/[a-z]+>)/i)]`, entonces, la etiqueta de apertura es `partes[1]`, la de cierre `partes[3]`, y el texto central es `partes[2]`... Hay que tener en cuenta que esta expresión regular no acepta atributos en la etiqueta, si se quiere con atributos tendría que ser un poco más compleja.

Comment: muchas gracias tienes algun ejemplo donde se de click a un boton y se adicione esta etiqueta y me permita escribir dentro de ella

Comment: @albertolg89 Hice un jsFiddle sobre eso, echale un vistazo... http://jsfiddle.net/ArtEze/m0wh6zrs/44/ Se selecciona el texto, y se toca F2 (tecla de ejemplo), luego escribes la etiqueta que quieras. No lo hago con botones porque pierde el foco.

Comment: muchas gracias. Es que quería tener unas etiquetas para que a la hora de procesar el texto pueda obtener lo que esta dentro. Ahora voy a trabajar para tratar de hacer que estas etiquetas utilizando un CKEDITOR aparezcan invisibles.