# ¿Cómo procesar el texto seleccionado en un DIV en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estoy haciendo un editor de texto para un proyecto, al principio, comencé utilizando un `TextArea` como la hoja en la que podría escribir el usuario y pude resolver algunos problemas gracias a esta pregunta hecha aquí mismo por otro usuario.
[Procesar el texto seleccionado de un área de texto en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55022/procesar-el-texto-seleccionado-de-un-%C3%A1rea-de-texto-en-javascript) 
Pero como un textarea es limitado para lo que quiero hacer o para la forma en la que lo quería hacer. Averigüé más y pues se puede hacer un DIV editable, pero a diferencia de un textarea, este no tiene las propiedad "`selectionStart`" y "`selectionEnd`". Entonces ¿cómo podría procesar el texto seleccionado dentro de un `div`?¿Cuáles serían las propiedades alternativas?

Aquí algo del código que intenta hacer eso: 
La etiqueta que llama a la función:

```
select id="Tamaño" onchange="cambiarTamaño()"> <br>
    option value="h1">Título</option> <br>
    option value="h2">Subtítulo</option> <br>
    option value="p">Normal</option> <br>
select> <br><br>
```

La función:

```
/* Se encarga de cambiar el tamaño de la fuente */  
function cambiarTamaño()  
{  
    //Obtine la opción seleccionada  
    var opcionSeleccionada = document.getElementById("Tamaño");

    //Obtiene el area de texto
    var hoja = document.getElementById("Hoja");

    //Texto que contiene
    var texto = window.getSelection().toString();

    //Le encimo la etiqueta que quiero
    texto = "<" + opcionSeleccionada.value + ">" + texto + "</" + opcionSeleccionada.value + ">";

    hoja.innerHTML = texto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción sería emplear el método [getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) del objeto `Window` o [getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection) de la interfaz `document`. Para validar y obtener la selección del contenido en el `div`. Antes de esto , debemos escuchar los eventos `mouseup` ,`keyup` y `touchend` del `div`. *(para el ejemplo además se ejecutó el comando para señalar en negrita el texto seleccionado)*

```js
var hoja = document.getElementById('Hoja');
['mouseup', 'keyup','touchend'].forEach(function(e){
 hoja.addEventListener(e,fnSeleccion,false);
});

function fnSeleccion() {
 var selection;  
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    selection = document.selection.createRange();
  }
  if(selection.toString()!==''){
   document.execCommand('bold');//Negrita el texto Seleccionado
   console.log(selection.toString());
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Hoja" contenteditable="true">
  Hola Mundo
</div>
```